# Load invalid Robot Framework XML Schema (xsd) using lxml python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xsd, lxml

I'm trying to validate the output.xml file from Robot Framework with officially provided [XML schema](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/schema/robot-xsd11.xsd):

For xml validation in Python I'm using [lxml library](https://lxml.de/).

```
    def validate_xml_file(schema, filename: str):
        log.info("Validating XML file: {}".format(filename))
        xsd_doc = etree.parse(schema)
        xsd = etree.XMLSchema(xsd_doc)
        xml = etree.parse(filename)
        result = xsd.assertValid(xml)
```

I'm getting following error:

```
  File "src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi", line 86, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': Invalid value for maxOccurs (must be 0 or 1)., line 19
```

As you can see in Robot Framework xsd file, line 19 is:
`<xs:element name="kw" type="kw" maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="0"/>` which means, there is an issue with **macOccurs="2"**. Do you know about some "nice" way, how to ignore this rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. lxml doesn't support XSD 1.1, it supports only XSD 1.0. So I just took the RobotFramework XSD 1.0 and now it works as expected.